# OSX AUGraph recreation causes badComponentType error

Tags: c++, macos, audio

On OSX I'm creating an AUGraph for my audio system like so:

```
OSStatus result = NewAUGraph(&mGraph);

AUNode outputNode;
AudioComponentDescription outputDesc;
outputDesc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
outputDesc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput;
outputDesc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
outputDesc.componentFlags = 0;
outputDesc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
result = AUGraphAddNode(mGraph, &outputDesc, &outputNode);

AUNode converterNode;
AudioComponentDescription converterDesc;
converterDesc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_FormatConverter;
converterDesc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_AUConverter;
converterDesc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
converterDesc.componentFlags = 0;
outputDesc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
result = AUGraphAddNode(mGraph, &converterDesc, &converterNode);

result = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(mGraph, converterNode, 0, outputNode, 0);
result = AUGraphOpen(mGraph);

...initialize graph, start graph, etc...
```

This all works fine, I can hear sound, etc. Later the system is shut down:

```
unsigned char isRunning = false;
AUGraphIsRunning(mGraph, &isRunning);
if (isRunning)
    AUGraphStop(mGraph);

OSStatus result;
unsigned char isInitialized = false;
AUGraphIsInitialized(mGraph, &isInitialized);
if (isInitialized)
{
    result = AUGraphUninitialize(mGraph);
}
result = DisposeAUGraph(mGraph);
```

Again, no problems here. However a short while after the first code block gets executed again when the system is restarted. On:

```
result = AUGraphOpen(mGraph);
```

"result" comes out as -2005 (badComponentType). Anyone know what causes this?

Answer (score 0):

Calling AUGraphClose in the shutdown fixed this. Guess you can't have two open graphs with the same output unit in?